# Connecting to data source using ssl in Karaf, getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/TrustManager

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm running Servicemix 6.1.3. I have a data source (.cfg-file) using ssl:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlcluster-test.dot.com:3306/mydb?useSSL=true
user=cs_dev
password=mypwd
```

When I deploy my bundle, I get this error message:

```
2018-03-20 14:02:51,054 | ERROR | mix-6.1.3/deploy | JdbcMessageIdRepository          | 251 - org.apache.camel.camel-sql - 2.16.4 | Can't create table for JdbcMessageIdRepository with query 'CREATE TABLE  MYTABLE(name VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(100), createdAt TIMESTAMP)' because of: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/TrustManager. This may be a permissions problem. Please create this table and try again.
2018-03-20 14:02:51,056 | ERROR | mix-6.1.3/deploy | BlueprintCamelContext            | 156 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.16.4 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(SystemIntegration.cu) due Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/TrustManager
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/TrustManager
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)[250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jdbc:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)[250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jdbc:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:428)[250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jdbc:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcMessageIdRepository$1.doInTransaction(JdbcMessageIdRepository.java:70)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-sql:2.16.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcMessageIdRepository$1.doInTransaction(JdbcMessageIdRepository.java:60)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-sql:2.16.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)[144:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcMessageIdRepository.doStart(JdbcMessageIdRepository.java:60)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-sql:2.16.4]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[151:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)[151:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)[151:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)[151:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
    ...
```

What do I have to do in order to use datasources using ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore with your trusted certificates.

There are any number of ways to achieve that, but a simple solution is to compile and run

[this program](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java)

as

```
java InstallCert hostname
```

Please give it a try and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, when you write "the server", do you mean the database server?

Comment: yes.. DB server host.Please give it a try and confirm if that works for you.

Comment: Where is it located? On the db server or on the app server?

Comment: You need to run "installcert" on the app server(host),where application is residing.